# /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced

Tags: boot, fsck

After booting into Ubuntu this shows up

[image: fsck needed]

```
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntuu2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)_
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

At the (initramfs) prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sda1` to check/repair your file system.

Comment: @erluxman Glad I could help!

Comment: `fsck -f /dev/sda1` is the life saver

Comment: Thank you, saved my day

Comment: @Piotr Great news!

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: worked perfectly for another files system error in my machine while booting. Thank you very much @heynnema

Comment: Works like a charm.