# Warning: Filesystem still has errors

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck

After I rebooted my Ubuntu (20.04) laptop, it hung at the purple screen and the login page never appeared. I pressed the power button to turn it off, and after I turned it on again, I ran into the exact same problem mentioned in this post:
[/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955467/dev-sda1-contains-a-file-system-with-errors-check-forced)

I followed the instruction given in that post and entered `fsck -f /dev/sda1` at the prompt and entered `y` when it asked `Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. Fix<y>?`

[/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KBzn.jpg)

After this, I answered no to all the `Free blocks count wrong` prompts. However, it still says Filesystem still has errors.
I was wondering if I could get some help on how to fix this, thank you!

[Filesystem still has errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ad6l.jpg)

Comment: If you answered `no` to those fix suggestions by fsck, it will leave it in an unrepaired state.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you so much!